# Week calculation from a specific period

Tags: sql, sql-server

suppose the fiscal year is starting from July/1st to June/30th.

I have to calculate the week no. accordingly in SQL Server 2005.

Please Suggest!

Many Thanks!

Comment: Is week one the first seven days from July 1st?  And thus, week 53 the last 1 *(or 2 in leap years)* days?

Comment: Do you start at week no 0 or no 1? What is your definition for the first week of the year?

Comment: Please use google before asking, be sure not to be asking something that is trivial finding even here on this same site. Either case, be more specific on your question and explain the details in order to get a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

If week 1 of your financial year is always 1st July to 7th July...

```
DECLARE
  @inputDate    DATETIME,
  @fYearStart   DATETIME,
  @weekNumber   INT
SET
  @inputDate    = getDate()
SET
  @fYearStart   = DATEADD(year, DATEDIFF(year, '20000101', DATEADD(month, -7, @inputDate)), '20000701')
SET
  @weekNumber   = DATEDIFF(day, @fYearStart, @inputDate) / 7 + 1
```

If your finacial weeks are always Sunday to Saturday...

```
DECLARE
  @inputDate    DATETIME,
  @fYearStart   DATETIME,
  @weekNumber   INT
SET
  @inputDate    = getDate()
SET
  @fYearStart   = DATEADD(year, DATEDIFF(year, '20000101', DATEADD(month, -7, @inputDate)), '20000701')
SET
  @weekNumber   = DATEDIFF(WEEK, @fYearStart, @inputDate)
```

One or other of these should be adaptable to *your* definition of `week number`.

Comment: In the calendar table I have date, fiscal_year, fiscal_period. How can I calculate weeknumber here in this table or view?

Comment: @user1571129 - Please include example data from that table in your question, and show examples of the result that you would like.  We can then write code that works for that example data.

Comment: If the week is starting from Monday.

Answer (score 1):

Try this and use variable @dt for your own needs:

```
DECLARE @dt DATETIME = GETDATE()
SELECT WeekOfMonth = DATEPART(wk, @dt) - DATEPART(wk,DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(M, 0, @dt), 0)) + 1
```

EDITED:
My fault as I incorrectly understood the question, my solution returns the week of the month, not of the year.

Using part of @Dems answer and changing mine here is a full working test that outputs 3 columns WeekOfMonth, WeekOfYear and WeekOfFIscalYear based on date and begining of fiscal year available on a temporary table. But I guess the begining of a fiscal year will be always the same for a particular company. I just added different dates and years for testing.

```
DECLARE @TT TABLE (auxVal       INT,
                   auxdate      DATETIME,
                   fiscal_year  DATETIME
                )

INSERT @TT 
SELECT 100,'19120101 00:00:00','19120701' UNION ALL
SELECT 200,'18120615 00:00:00','18110701' UNION ALL
SELECT 100,'20121121 00:00:00','20120701' UNION ALL
SELECT 200,'20120101 00:00:00','20110701' UNION ALL
SELECT 100,'20150802 00:00:00','20140701' UNION ALL
SELECT 200,'20120330 00:00:00','20110701' UNION ALL
SELECT 322,'20110228 00:00:00','20100701'

SELECT DATEDIFF(week, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, auxDate), 0), auxDate) + 1 WeekOfMonth,
       DATEPART( wk, auxDate) WeekOfYear,
       DATEDIFF(DAY, (DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, fiscal_year, DATEADD(MONTH, -7, auxDate)), fiscal_year)), auxDate) / 7 + 1  WeekOfFiscalYear
  FROM @TT
```

Result:

```
WeekOfMonth   WeekOfYear   WeekOfFiscalYear
-------------------------------------------
      1            1             27
      3            25            51
      4            47            21
      1            1             27
      2            32            5
      5            13            40
      5            10            35
-------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Why does this round the input to the begining of the month? And the basic approach `DATEPART(wk, x) - DATEPART(wk, y)` yields negative numbers where x is earlier in the year than y, even if x is in the year *after* y.

Comment: Sorry folks, I do not know how are you testing. I'm testing with several different dates and I get the correct answer.

Comment: (DATEDIFF(day, '2012-07-01',calendar_date)/7)+1  AS WEEK by this query I am getting the week number also. But here the week is starting from sunday to saturday. But I want it from sunday to monday. how can I achieve it?

Comment: +1 This latter solution worked nicely for me but I modified it for the academic year so that the first Monday of August is Week 1.

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me:

```
SELECT dt AS DayDate,
CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATENAME(weekday,dt)) AS [DayOfWk],
CONVERT(int,CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEPART(yyyy,dt)) + RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEPART(wk,dt)),2)) AS [WeekID],
'Week ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEPART(wk,dt))AS [WeekDsc],
DATEPART(wk,dt) AS [WeekNbr],
DATEADD(dd, -(DATEPART(dw, dt)-1), dt) AS [WeekStartDay],
DATEADD(dd, 7-(DATEPART(dw, dt)), dt) AS [WeekEndDay],
CONVERT(VARCHAR,CASE WHEN DATEPART(mm,dt) > 6 THEN DATEPART(yyyy,dt) + 1 ELSE DATEPART(yyyy,dt) END) + RIGHT('00'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEDIFF(week,DATEADD(dd, 7-(DATEPART(dw, CASE WHEN DATEPART(mm,dt) > 6 THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEPART(yyyy,dt)) + '-07-01' ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEPART(yyyy,dt) - 1) + '-07-01' END)), CASE WHEN DATEPART(mm,dt) > 6 THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEPART(yyyy,dt)) + '-07-01' ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEPART(yyyy,dt) - 1) + '-07-01' END) + 1,DATEADD(dd, -(DATEPART(dw, dt)-1), dt)) + 2) ,2) AS [FinWkID]
FROM 
(
    SELECT DATEADD(day,increment,'2014-01-01') dt
    FROM
    (
        SELECT top 5000 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s1.[object_id]) - 1 AS increment
        FROM sys.all_objects AS s1
        CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects AS s2
        ORDER BY s1.[object_id]
    ) SQ
) DATE_GENERATOR
```

Answer (score 0):

Without the need of creating a table.
Just replace the @date with your column date name

```
declare @date datetime
set     @date = '12/8/2016 00:00:00'

select  case when datepart(month,@date) > 6 then 

            case when CEILING(datediff(day,'6/30/' + cast(datepart(year,@date) as nvarchar(4)),@date) / 7.0) > 52
            then 52 else CEILING(datediff(day,'6/30/' + cast(datepart(year,@date) as nvarchar(4)),@date) / 7.0) end

        else
            case when CEILING(datediff(day,'6/30/' + cast(datepart(year,@date)-1 as nvarchar(4)),@date) / 7.0) > 52
            then 52 else CEILING(datediff(day,'6/30/' + cast(datepart(year,@date)-1 as nvarchar(4)),@date) / 7.0) end
        end WorkWeek
```

[Compute Week number based on Fiscal Year](http://rmchio.blogspot.com/2016/08/compute-week-number-per-fiscal-year.html)

Answer (score -1):

```
try this

    select DATEPART(week,getdate())-DATEPART(week,'07-01-2012')

To get the week number starting from July 1st 2012
```

Comment: If the input date is `1st Jan 2013`, this returns a negative value.

Comment: This query is only giving me current week. I have to list all the week number from fiscal year 2000.

Comment: Usually SQL server refreshes the week numbers starting of each new year.It means it calculates the week number starting from 01-01-2012 for example.So do you like to reset the week numbers every time the year changes or you want to get total number of weeks since 01-01-2000?