# Add column for Fiscal Week in an SQL SELECT Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below mentioned is my Query:

```
SELECT DPSNumber, StatusDateTime FROM DispatchTool
```

The Resulst is:

```
DPSNumber   StatusDateTime
123123526   8/4/14 12:00 AM
123123527   8/5/14 12:00 AM
123123528   8/6/14 12:00 AM
123123529   8/7/14 12:00 AM
```

I want to add an additional column to this result as shown below:

```
DPSNumber   StatusDateTime  FiscalWeek
123123526   8/4/14 12:00 AM 27
123123527   8/5/14 12:00 AM 27
123123528   8/6/14 12:00 AM 27
123123529   8/7/14 12:00 AM 27
```

Fiscal Week for my Organization started on January 31, 2014

Comment: what is the logic behind `FiscalWeek` can't map anything from sample data

Comment: Write a function that calculates the fiscal week from a date (i.e. week number of year - week number of fiscal year start) and add the function call to the query `SELECT DPSNumber, StatusDateTime, CalcFiscalWeek(StatusDateTime) AS FiscalWeek FROM DispatchTool`

Comment: FiscalWeek should be a Calculated Column. This column should display the Fiscal Week Calculated Using the values from StatusDateTime Column.

Comment: A fiscal week is the week number of a specific date according to a BUSINESS year. Since not all business years start on Jan 1...

Comment: Well then you need to write your own function where you tell the function the current year, the first fiscal day.

Comment: @Robert Thanks for your response. Can you please explain how to go about creating the function CalcFiscalWeek()? As stated earlier "Fiscal Year for my Organization started on January 31, 2014".

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11775881/week-calculation-from-a-specific-period

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `DateDiff Function` is what you need

```
SELECT DPSNumber,
       StatusDateTime,
       Datediff(wk, CONVERT(DATE, 'January 31, 2014'), CONVERT(DATE, StatusDateTime)) FiscalWeek
From   Tablename
```